# Posting or Getting value to another page rather than posting it to the next page on php

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I want to pass my values to the page that won't be on next page but on another page. For example I have inputs in Page1, but this page goes to Page2. And I need the values on Page3. I used to use session and cookies but my REST API resets them and I need to use another method to pass the varaibles. I searched for AJAX but couldn't find the right method to do that.

Comment: so send from `page 1` get in `page 2` and than send again from `page 2` to `page 3` and get on `page 3`

Comment: I am using paypal REST Api and it redirects to the paypal page, I can't control those pages. I need to get the value from checkout page to the paymentdone page but after checout page, it goes to paypal page. I only need that value on paymentdone page.